# JHipster liquibase not ready after choosing oracle db in dev & prod

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I generated my app using JHipster, I chose Oracle database in dev and prod. then in `application-dev.yml`, `application-prod.yml` and in `pom.xml` I set the username, the password and the name of my Oracle database. When I run `mvnw` I got this

```
2022-04-01 02:36:55.530  WARN 3020 --- [on-rd-vs-task-1] t.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase     : Starting Liquibase asynchronously, your database might not be ready at startup!
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using liquibase in async mode.

The goal of this message is to remind you that your application might have started whereas the database is not ready.

If you want your database be ready once your application is started, you have to run liquibase in sync mode.

Answer (score 0):

The JHipster generate the `LiquibaseConfiguration` and by default the Liquibase start asynchronously:

```
SpringLiquibase liquibase = SpringLiquibaseUtil.createAsyncSpringLiquibase(...)
```

and there were also code left there to start it in sync mode:

```
// If you don't want Liquibase to start asynchronously, substitute by this:
SpringLiquibase liquibase = SpringLiquibaseUtil.createSpringLiquibase(...)
```

You can comment the async code and uncomment the sync one to run liquibase in sync mode.